Can you allow S3 HeadBucket without granting unrestricted access to list objects?
This feels like a silly question or like I am missing a simple solution. However, I have an IAM role which grants permission to list objects only in some prefixes in my bucket. Listing is done directory-style, hence the delimiter/prefix conditions.
  {
    "Effect":   "Allow",
    "Action":   [ "s3:ListBucket" ],
    "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket" ],
    "Condition": { 
      "StringEquals": { 
        "s3:prefix":    [ <<ALLOWED-PREFIXES>> ],
        "s3:delimiter": [ "/" ]
      }
  }

The role also needs to have permission to call the HeadBucket API.
Both ListObjectsV2 and HeadBucket require the s3:ListBucket permission. However, the above policy is causing a Forbidden response when calling HeadBucket. I had hoped to find some condition key such that I can add a statement allowing HeadBucket to succeed while maintaining restricted prefix access - eg aws:http-method=HEAD or s3:operation=head-bucket. However, that doesn't seem to exist.
Am I missing something? Or is this just the desired/expected behavior from S3 HeadObject since the role does not have FULL access to the bucket?
